# If label text is "Engine Capacity" then only get text of that element which is in front of "Engine Capacity"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a label "Engine Capacity" and in front of that label there is an element whose text "1328". how can i get text of that element if and only if the element is in front of "Engine Capacity" label.

xpath of Label: //*[@id="ownershipDiv"]/dl/dt[11]/label

xpath of element which is infront of label: //*[@id="ownershipDiv"]/dl/dd[11]

html text is :

```
<dt style="width:100px;"><label>Engine Capacity</label></dt>    
<dd>1328</dd>
```

Comment: Might be easiest go go through a parent item. Maybe you can share a bit larger piece of html ?

Comment: @Chai thats all the html is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
//dt[contains(.,'Engine Capacity')]/following-sibling::dd[1]
```

This will select the first sibling 'dd' element following a 'dt' element containing the text 'Engine Capacity'